# Node.js update cell in csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js

CSV file has multiple rows. How can I update specific cell for given row?

I have looked at various npm modules and am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You can parse a csv file by reading the file then using `var lineArray = file.split('\n')`. Then each line will represent an array index.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something such as [Baby Parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babyparse)

Baby Parse is the node version of the javascript Papa Parse. With Baby Parse you can load either a local or remote file, parse it so it returns an Array of rows which is essentially an two dimensional array that contains all of your cells, and then edit whichever cell you want.

From the npm description:

```
parsed = Baby.parse(csv);

rows = parsed.data;
```

Now simply go through each index of rows to edit the cell you want.

Answer (score -1):

You Can try with csv-cell-editor module which update the specific cell in csv file.

Example:

let csvEditor = require('csv-editor');

let options = { 
fileName: ''example.csv",
cellAddress: 'H7"', 
cellValue: ''updated value"
};

csvEditor(options);

Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-cell-editor